# Im confused why Im getting no output when using a bash variable and I can't set it properly Can someone fix my code

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

I created a `.sh` file that is supposed to run the `cat` command on a text file then replace part of the text and echo it back.

The file name that I'm running the `cat` command on is "New" with the content `Hello` and the executable script is:

```sh
alias message="cat ~/ll/New"
echo "${message//ello/X}
```

Comment: That's not how variables work in Shell scripts. You're supposed to set it to a name of an environment variable. `alias` is used for aliasing commands so that they can be easily entered into the terminal.

Comment: @RonanLeonard : You don't run a _cat_ command in your example. You just manipulate a variable called `message`, which never gets a value, so it won't output anything.

Answer (score 0):

alias command does not assign a variable
So ${message) is empty

Probably you  should use message as a command not as variable